# err_empty_response error when clicking a button

Tags: php, html, web, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I have a website, and all its files (html/js/css/php) are on the same remote host. I have a button on the site, when clicked it sends a httprequest to a PHP file, waiting for a response.

My site works perfect almost everywhere, but there is one place which when I connect to the wi-fi, when clicking the button it return whit the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Other buttons and PHP files work. It is only this specific button and in this specific wi-fi.

Does anyone know why does it happen and how to fix it?

details:

- the button is `<button class="btn btn-default col-sm-5" type="submit">`
- the onClick function:

  `function search() {
      var param = "";
      var firstParam = true;
      var form = document.getElementById("formCS");
      var name = document.getElementById("songName").value.trim();
      if (name != "") {
          firstParam = false;
          param += "name=" + name;
      }
      var creator = document.getElementById("creator").value.trim();
      if (creator != "") {
          if (firstParam) {
              param += "creator=" + creator;
              firstParam = false;
          } else {
              param += "&creator=" + creator;
          }
      }
      var type;
      if (document.getElementById("partners").checked) {
          type = "partners";
      } else if (document.getElementById("circle").checked) {
          type = "circle";
      } else if (document.getElementById("lines").checked) {
          type = "lines";
      } else if (document.getElementById("none").checked) {
          type = "";
      }
      if (type != "") {
          if (firstParam) {
              param += "type=" + type;
              firstParam = false;
          } else {
              param += "&type=" + type;
          }
      }
      var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
      if (year != "none") {
          if (firstParam) {
              param += "year=" + year;
          } else {
              param += "&year=" + year;
          }
      }
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              handleResponse(xhttp.response);
          }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "search.php?" + param, true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send();
  }`
- the search.php file connects to a DB on the remote host and runs a sql query. nothing different from other buttons on the site.
- the wi-fi is a free wi-fi provided by an academic institue.
- after clicking the button there is an error in the console:

GET http://rikudim.info/search.php? net::ERR_EMPTY_REPONSE

Comment: How do you expect us to answer without you giving us details? What kind of "button" is that? What request does it trigger? What do your server side log files say? What is specific about that network? What does your browsers console reveal?

Comment: @arkascha like what? I can post all the code in all the files, but it's not effective. What specific details do you need?

Comment: Didn't I write that in my comment?

Comment: @arkascha hope it helps

Comment: _What does your browsers console reveal?_

Comment: _What do your server side log files say?_

Comment: I don't know how to access the logs or where are they. I use freehosting

Comment: You need to find out. You have to anyway. You cannot develop php in a web environment without monitoring the log files when issues arise. Ask your hosting provider.

Comment: until I found where are the log files (if there are any), is there something else I can do trying to fix it? like i said, it happens only in a specific wi-fi. At home it works without any problems

Comment: When you debug an issue there is little sense in trying to _guess_ a solution. You debug an issue by looking at the evidence, here log files and your browsers console output. You need to learn those things anyway, so why not get started?

Comment: @arkascha I added the error appearing in the browser console. I stil don't know where are the log files.

Comment: That error message suggests an issue with the (local) network connection, not with your server side implementation or setup. Something that actually matches with your impression that the issue is limited to a certain WiFi network. Nevertheless it would be very interesting to see what your http servers error log file says about those requests. Just take a look into your http servers documentation to find out where those are located. About the networking issue: a starting point would be a network sniffer or even the client side system log files.

Comment: the hosting provider haven't answered yet to my question about the server's log files, and there is no documentation to where those are. Where can I find the client side log files? And is there another way maybe to rewrite the php file so that it will work?

Comment: Without knowing what the actual cause of the issue is, what do you want to do then? Fixing an issue is not done by doing "something", you have know exactly what to do! And as said before: to me this looks like an issue with that network, not with your code.